# Catch all invokeAction requests in JavaScript

Tags: javascript-remoting, remote-objects

I use Angular.js and this [github.com example](https://github.com/joelw377/ItemHunter/blob/master/salesforce/src/staticresources/script_utils.resource) to invoke remote action

```
 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction.apply(
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager, args);
```

I need to 'hook' all this SF requests/responses on a page to save arguments.
Like:
 
[Add a “hook” to all AJAX requests on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page) or 
[catch all ajax requests in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043768/catch-all-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

I don't want to save arguments before .apply line:

```
saveArguments(args);
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction.apply(
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager, args);
```

I need to make separated service/module.

I'm going to override the native invokeAction(). Is it good way? If invokeAction uses AJAX, I can't find anything in Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction related with AJAX.

So could you give me some tips how I can... maybe... only override the native invokeAction() or you know better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just used these approaches [Add a “hook” to all AJAX requests on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page).
jQuery approach [catch all ajax requests in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043768/catch-all-ajax-requests-in-jquery) don't work for me.